# Does not autoresize when device is rotated after loading nibfromfile

Tags: objective-c

I have the following question:

I got some code that gets called when an user logs in. The code has to call another view controller and has to show another view. To show to new view, i got the following code:

```
[scrollView removeFromSuperview];

Form1 *formcontroller1 = [[Form1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Form1" bundle:[NSBundle     mainBundle]];

[self.view setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

[self.view addSubview:formcontroller1.view];

[scrollView release];
```

The problem is, when the other view is loaded and i rotate the device, the view of the new nib is not resizing correctly.

EDIT:

I wasn't dismissing the current viewcontroller so some properties remained. What i did is this:

```
[scrollView removeFromSuperview];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Form1 *formcontroller = [[Form1 alloc] init];

[self presentModalViewController:formcontroller animated:YES];

[scrollView release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the autoresizing properties of your nib view in Interface Builder...

It should look like in the picture:

[image]

The middle arrows are dimmed, but still active. This is where autoresizing is set. You could try and set that property programmatically by assigning in your controller `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

You should also ensure that both your view and its superviewhave the "autoresize subviews" button checked (in the first pane of the inspector in IB)

OLD ANSWER:

How is `Form1` [– shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:) defined?

> By default, this method returns YES for the UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait orientation only. If your view controller supports additional orientations, override this method and return YES for all orientations it supports.
>
> Your implementation of this method should simply return YES or NO based on the value in the interfaceOrientation parameter. Do not attempt to get the value of the interfaceOrientation property or check the orientation value reported by the UIDevice class. Your view controller is either capable of supporting a given orientation or it is not.

E.g.:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {   
   return YES;
}
```

to support all orientations.

Comment: In Form1.m i got the following:

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
 return YES;
}

Comment: I am really sorry... I overlooked the word "resizing" in your question and thought it was not rotating... :-( see my edit, though, hope this helps...

Comment: Thats ok, but that didn't answered my question either. The problem is that i can't get the view to resize, only anchoring. So the two arrows in the middle are disabled..

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand... do you mean that IB does not let you enable the arrows in the middle (those that mean "autoresize")? On which object are you trying it? is it a view?

Comment: Yes, thats correct what you say. I am trying it on a view object. Because when i call the view in portrait mode, the width is 768 and the height is 1024. When i rotate it into landscape mode the view stays to keep the same dimensions. But the content in the view DOES rotate.

Comment: would you set a colored background to your view so that you see if the view is resized after rotating? possibly the view content is not set in IB so that it resizes too (hence, the view resizes, but its content doesn't)...

Comment: I did set a dark blue background. When the device is in portrait mode, the views background fills up the entire screen. When i tilt the device into landscape mode, the width of 768px stays the same and fills up about 2/3 of the screen. So there is a big white bar next to the view.

Comment: Why does the view not receives a message to resize itself according to the orientation? Is that set in the appdelegate or something?

Comment: It is set where I showed you in the picture. I changed the picture to reflect what I see in IB with a view that resizes correctly (mid arrows are dimmed but set). Also, added some bit about setting the autoresizing programmatically...

Comment: Thank you very much. That almost helped all my problems. Unfortunately there is still a problem with the position of the view:

When the application is started in portrait mode, and i log in. The view fills up the entire screen. Also when i rotate the device. But in the IB i defined the mode of the view to portrait.

When i log in to the application in landscape mode, the view is to narrow because i set the view in ib to be portrait. When i rotate back to portrait the view stays to small, because it now resizes well.

Comment: I am not sure I understand... the portrait/landscape setting in IB only affects the way the view is displayed in IB, not in your app... as you can see those settings are in the section "simulated UI...". could you post some picture as to what is happening now?

Comment: I can't upload pictures since my rep is not 10. But i will try to explain it as clearly as possible:

When the application starts, and the device is in landscape mode. And i log in to the application, the above code is used to dismiss to login view and call the form view. When i set the simulated metrics to landscape the device is showing the view correctly (right dimensions). If i then rotate the device when i logged in, the view resizes because of the:

    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Comment: But when i start the application in portrait mode, the view what is called after login, is still showed in landscape. Because of this, the screen is to small to display the view in landscape mode. The half of the content is showed offscreen.

Comment: You mean that `Form1` does not rotate when you start in portrait and it is always shown in landscape? on the other hand, when you start in landscape, everything is ok because everything is landscape. In this case, can you rotate to portrait? does it work? in the above code, is `self` set to autorotate in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`?

Comment: In all of the viewcontrollers:

"shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" is set to yes.

Comment: I already fixed my problem. I will add the code in my first post.